# `system()` interactive .exe/binary from R/Rgui

Tags: r

I'd like to run an interactive binary using `system()` within R.

By interactive, suppose I wanted to run the python command-line interpreter from within R (who knows why, but in any case...).

When I run R from the command line (i.e. Rterm), I can start up the python interpreter like so:

```
> system('python.exe')
Python 2.7.2 on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> # I can now type in python commands and basically use the python 
    # interpreter until I've had enough. 
    # Now I'll exit the python interpreter:
>>> exit()
> # Presto, I'm back to the R prompt!
```

The point is, I can interact with the python interpreter from R just as if I'd started the interpreter from the command line in the first place, and I can exit it when I'm done to get back to the R prompt.

Now, let's try the same with the R GUI:

```
> system('python.exe')
Python 2.7.2 on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
> # eh? it exitted?
```

This just runs python.exe (displaying that welcome message), but then quits straight away - I can't interact with the python interpreter.

My question is -- is there any way (in R GUI, ie the windows one) to run that interpreter and interact with it in the same way that works from any command-line version of R?

(FYI - when I first started learning how to write R packages, my goal as my first ever R package was just to be able to play [nethack](http://www.nethack.org/) in R. Worked beautifully (I use linux & hence the command-line R), except when I took it to the windows RGui it would start the process but not be interactive, effectively locking up R until I forcibly ended the NetHack.exe process).

Comment: I can get this to run by doing `system('python.exe',invisible=FALSE,wait=FALSE)`, but this does launch the entire thing in a new command prompt window, whereas I'd prefer it to happen from the R terminal.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what you want is impossible using Rgui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked it out - had to read the help file under Windows (turns out the unix & windows `?system` differ):

> Do not try to run console applications that require user input from `Rgui` setting `intern=TRUE` or `show.output.on.console=TRUE`. They will not work.

So looks like the best I'll get (from Rgui anyhow) is a new window being launched:

```
system('NetHack.exe',invisible=FALSE,wait=FALSE)
```

I'll add a `if ( .Platform$GUI == "Rgui" )` check for this and set the parameters appropriately.

(Huzzah, onwards the quest of the NetHackR!)