# Execute a terminal command which requires user input

Tags: r, macos

How can I execute a system command that normally requires user interaction? For example, I would like to run:

```
system("ssh-keygen")
```

At the terminal prompt, it looks like this:

```
iMac-2:~ admin$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/admin/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

In RStudio, this command causes the application to hang.

I've tried the options `wait=FALSE`, AND `invisible=FALSE`, but they don't seem to help.

[R: Using wait=FALSE in system() with multiline commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257271/r-using-wait-false-in-system-with-multiline-commands)

[`system()` interactive .exe/binary from R/Rgui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612509/system-interactive-exe-binary-from-r-rgui/9613038#9613038)

Comment: `system` function has an `input=` parameter. You could try to code user input into this parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.

There are some commands who let you to put the parameters in command line:

For example:

`ssh-keygen`

If you run: `ssh-keygen --help` you could find something like this:

`ssh-keygen -c [-P passphrase] [-C comment] [-f keyfile]`

It says you could specify the parameters in command line.

In my case I've tested with:

`ssh-keygen -f /tmp/id_rsa -P ""`

And I don't need to interact with the program.

Like another example like `adduser` command, you could try with:

`echo PASSWORD | passwd USERNAME --stdin`

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Do you know if there's a way to provide the password with `scp` and `ssh`?

Comment: There is a command named 'sshpass' but....i dont think it could be a great way to use pass a password, because you could use it in a script and somebody could read the password. I think you could configure a 'Trust Relationship' between your hosts, it could help you too.